# Is there a complete list of defaults / plist settings for the dock?

Tags: dock, plist, defaults

I know that most of the `defaults` settings for macOS components are probably hidden or undocumented, but I'm curious if there is someone who has compiled a complete list or if there is a way to discover what options are available?

In particular, I've become annoyed by how quickly the dock seems to follow my mouse to my 2nd monitor (but seems to delay coming back to primary), so I'm looking to see if there are any settings which could influence the behavior of this.

Comment: The first question linked on top of your post actually show how to list all *configured* defaults for the Dock :-)

Answer (score 0):

Each of the lists or applications below include Dock adjustments and default settings. None claim to be complete:

- [mathiasbynens' dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos)
- [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/details.html)
- [defaults-write.com](https://www.defaults-write.com)
- [Deeper / Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/index.html)
- [Global defaults in macOS Mojave](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/08/15/global-defaults-in-macos-mojave/)